# I am everywhere

Tags: riddle, word

I am a word.

A single vowel word.

> Add a consonant up front: I become deadly
>
> Add a consonant inside: I become a very big place
>
> Replace the end consonant: I become a living thing
>
> Replace the front consonant: I become powerful
>
> Turn me around: I become-kind of-wet.

Can you guess this word?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are the single-vowel word:

> **WORD**!

*Add a consonant up front: I become deadly*

> Add an 'S' to the front to get **SWORD**, a deadly weapon.

*Add a consonant inside: I become a very big place*

> Add an 'L' inside to get **WORLD** - a whole planet!

*Replace the end consonant: I become a living thing*

> Change 'D' to 'M' to get **WORM** - a living thing.

*Replace the front consonant: I become powerful*

> Change 'W' to 'L' to get **LORD** - a powerful master.

*Turn me around: I become-kind of-wet.*

> Reverse WORD to get **[DROW](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drow)** - a Scottish word for a gust of wind and rain.

You really are everywhere, aren't you - especially in this puzzle...

> ...not just in the form of miscellaneous words on this page, but you've also been explicitly mentioned three times in the text and again in the question tag!

Comment: That was ultra fast. Incredible.

Comment: @DrD Ha, thanks :) I'm not even sure I can explain how I found it so quickly, the last few minutes are a blur...! I guess something just *clicked* when I saw the puzzle, in a kind of 'let's try this' way, and it fell out - only the last line took a quick dictionary search to explain :)

Answer (score 2):

Very much a stretch, but

You are the single-vowel word:

> **POS**

*Add a consonant up front: I become deadly*

> Add an 'K' to the front to get **KPOS**, a firearm.

*Add a consonant inside: I become a very big place*

> Add an 'L' inside to get **POLS** - a municipality in Austria

*Replace the end consonant: I become a living thing*

> Change 'S' to 'M' to get **POM** - Pomeranian, a breed of dog.

*Replace the front consonant: I become powerful*

> Change 'P' to 'D' to get **DOS** - The Department of State (United States).

*Turn me around: I become-kind of-wet.*

> Reverse POS to get **[SOP](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sop)** - a piece of food soaked or dipped in a liquid.

I'll see myself out